# Move Data from SQL Server VM to SQL Server VM on a daily basis

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I would like to know what is the fastest way to export the data of 40 tables around 500 MB each one (Biggest one 17 GB) of a SQL Server instance in Azure to a different SQL Server instance in Azure same data center on a daily basis so we can schedule the process very early and get the latest data available once we arrive to the work. Some options are generating raw files and FTP the files to the other server using SSIS, using DTS or use the copy tool of Azure Data Factory.

Thanks,
Vlad

Comment: "Fastest" way, "best" way, etc. are broad, opinion-soliciting style questions. As far as actual processes and procedures though, best to ask at dba.stackexchange.com, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's probably quickest to do the copy way down at the managed disk level... but I'll let an Azure VM expert expand on that.

Comment: @Vladimir R, I hope that your question was answered. If so, can you consider to mark it as such one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** this post is based pretty much  on a personal opinion

Because you need to do it on a scheduled basis and performance is important perhaps such approach is a way to go:

1. Create a staging database [ExportDB] with simple recovery
2. Perform series of `SELECT * INTO [ExportDB].dbo.Table1 FROM YourDB.dbo.Table1`. Such approach involves BULK LOAD during the data load
3. Backup database with compression directly to azure blob storage
4. Restore ExportDB on another server from azure blob storage

---

References:

[Use Azure Storage for SQL Server Backup and Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-use-storage-sql-server-backup-restore)

Comment: Or just take nights backup and use that directly... but of course we don't have enough info to be able to suggest this.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, yeps, if tables for export cumulatively have size 2/3 of the entire database ))